# Cassandra 1.1 and later vs. JNA

Tags: cassandra

The Cassandra 1.1 documentation here: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/new_features mentions that the Off-Heap Cache has been re-written and doesn't have the JNA dependency anymore. But http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/install/install_jre still discusses the need of installing JNA in production.

The question is: Does it make sense to still install and use JNA via the external JARs? I understand that Cassandra doesn't support JNA on Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess it still makes sense since Cassandra uses JNA for creating hardlinks when taking snapshots and also to prevent the JVM to be swapped out by the OS by calling the mlockall() function through JNA.